# Ngx-datatable Refresh rows

Tags: angular, refresh, ngx-datatable

Trying ngx-datatable (version 11) with Angular-5 for the first time, rows load fine when loading during ngInit, but when lazy-loading, during a user search request, it shows the total of rows in the table, shows the first row, but not the rest of the rows. Basically, the page size remains as 1, but when loading from the ngInit, it calculates the right page size. Is there any way to make the table recalculate the size as it does during the init load ?

-thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the [scrollbarv]="true" parameter prevents the rows from expanding. I removed this line and set the [rowHeight]="50" and it works fine now.